# How to find number of similar addresses for each customer?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I have a dataset with two columns: customer `id` and `addresses`:

```
id      addresses
1111    asturias 32, benito juarez, CDMX
1111    JOSE MARIA VELASCO, CDMX
1111    asturias 32 DEPT 401, INSURGENTES, CDMX
1111    deportes
1111    asturias 32, benito juarez, MIXCOAC, CDMX
1111    cd. de los deportes
1111    deportes, wisconsin
2222    TORRE REFORMA LATINO, CDMX
2222    PERISUR 2890
2222    WE WORK, CDMX
2222    WEWORK, TORRE REFORMA LATINO, CDMX
2222    PERISUR: 2690, COYOCAN
2222    TORRE REFORMA LATINO
```

I am interested to find number of different addresses for each customers. For example, for the customer `id` 1111, there are 3 different addresses:

1. `[asturias 32, benito juarez, CDMX,
    asturias 32 DEPT 401, INSURGENTES, CDMX,
    asturias 32, benito juarez, MIXCOAC, CDMX]`
2. `[JOSE MARIA VELASCO, CDMX]`
3. `[deportes,
    cd. de los deportes,
    deportes, wisconsin]`

I wrote a code in python which can only show similarity between two consecutive rows: row `i` and row `i+1` (score of 0 means completely dissimilar and 1 means completely similar).

```
id      addresses                                  score
1111    asturias 32, benito juarez, CDMX             0
1111    JOSE MARIA VELASCO, CDMX                     0
1111    asturias 32 DEPT 401, INSURGENTES, CDMX      0
1111    deportes                                     0
1111    asturias 32, benito juarez, MIXCOAC, CDMX    0
1111    cd. de los deportes                          0.21
1111    deportes, wisconsin                          0
2222    TORRE REFORMA LATINO, CDMX                   0
2222    PERISUR 2890                                 0
2222    WE WORK, CDMX                                0.69
2222    WEWORK, TORRE REFORMA LATINO, CDMX           0
2222    PERISUR: 2690, COYOCAN                       0
2222    TORRE REFORMA LATINO
```

If score > 0.20, I am considering them two different addresses. Following is my code:

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import re
import unicodedata
import unidecode
import string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

data=pd.read_csv('address.csv')
nltk.download('punkt')
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

'''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(
        nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0, 1]

cnt = np.array(np.arange(0, 5183))
indx = []

for i in cnt:
    print cosine_sim(data['address'][i], data['address'][i + 1])
```

But above code is not able to compare each possible rows for a particular customer `id`. I want output like below:

```
id     unique address
1111    3
2222    3
3333    2
```

Comment: for addresses might it be better to first identify standard elements of the address? town, post code, street, etc, then sort these into separate columns: e.g. write regex for street names: `re.compile(r'([0-9]+[A-z]?) ([-\.A-z0-9 ]+ (?:street|place|close))')`, use a list of all city names if you work with data from limited number of countries, etc

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to parse the data or are you asking about multidimentional cosine differences?

Comment: I want to do multidimensional cosine differences. For example, if a customer made 4 transactions, with 4 addresses, say, add1, add2, add3, add4, I want to calculate cosine differences for 4C2 = 6 combinations: (add1, ad2), (add1, add3), (add1, add4), (add2, add3), (add2, add4), (add3, add4). I want to do it for every customers.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combinations in itertools for this purpose. Please see the complate code below.

Please note that I used semicolon separated CSV file

Also, you can use `similarity` function in `SPACY` to find similarity between two phrases if you want. Here I used the same function provided by you.

```
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import string
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer


def stem_tokens(tokens):
    return [stemmer.stem(item) for item in tokens]

'''remove punctuation, lowercase, stem'''
def normalize(text):
    return stem_tokens(
        nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punctuation_map)))

def cosine_sim(text1, text2):
    tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform([text1, text2])
    return ((tfidf * tfidf.T).A)[0, 1]

def group_addresses(addresses):
    '''merge the lists if they have an element in common'''
    out = []
    while len(addresses)>0:
        # first, *rest = addresses  # for python 3
        first, rest = addresses[0], addresses[1:]  # for python2
        first = set(first)
        lf = -1
        while len(first)>lf:
            lf = len(first)

            rest2 = []
            for r in rest:
                if len(first.intersection(set(r)))>0:
                    first |= set(r)
                else:
                    rest2.append(r)     
            rest = rest2

        out.append(first)
        addresses = rest
    return out


df=pd.read_csv("address.csv", sep=";")
stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
remove_punctuation_map = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=normalize, stop_words='english')

sim_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'unique address'])

for customer in set(df['id']):
    customer_addresses = (df.loc[df['id'] == customer]['addresses'])    #Get the addresses of each customer
    all_entries = [[adr] for adr in customer_addresses]    #Make list of lists
    sim_pairs = [list((text1, text2)) for text1, text2 in itertools.combinations(customer_addresses, 2) if cosine_sim(text1, text2) >0.2 ]      # Find all pairs whose similiarty is greater than 0.2
    all_entries.extend(sim_pairs)
    sim_pairs = group_addresses(all_entries)
    print(customer , len(sim_pairs))
```

Output looks like

```
2222 2
1111 3
```

The groups formed are

```
2222
['WE WORK, CDMX', 'WEWORK, TORRE REFORMA LATINO, CDMX', 'TORRE REFORMA LATINO, CDMX', 'TORRE REFORMA LATINO']
['PERISUR 2890', 'PERISUR: 2690, COYOCAN']

1111
['asturias 32 DEPT 401, INSURGENTES, CDMX', 'asturias 32, benito juarez, MIXCOAC, CDMX', 'asturias 32, benito juarez, CDMX']
['JOSE MARIA VELASCO, CDMX']
['deportes, wisconsin', 'cd. de los deportes', 'deportes']
```

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried to run your code but I am getting an error:       File "<ipython-input-14-4e68ec561d81>", line 25
    first, *rest = addresses
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Okay. I assume you are using python 2.7, my code is working in python 3. For python 2 please change the line   `first, *rest = addresses` to  `first, rest = addresses[0], addresses[1:]`  . Edited the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code is working properly. Yes, I am using python 2.7.